# Casting of `arrayfire::Array`

Tags: casting, rust, arrayfire

I'm using the [arrayfire](https://crates.io/crates/arrayfire) crate to open an image with `af::load_image`. This gives me a `f32` array that I can do some processing on. After I am done, I would like to save it as an `u8` image using `af::save_image`:

```
extern crate arrayfire as af;

fn main() {
    let im = af::load_image("image".into(), false);
    //let im2: af::Array = im.cast(); // Error: cannot infer type for T
    //let im2: af::Array<DType::U8> = im.cast(); // Error: expected no type arguments
}
```

I can't figure out how to convert the array into a `u8` type. I looked into the `from` method but I have no idea how to use it.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE], otherwise we will be blindly guessing over what the concrete issue might be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature for [`cast`](http://arrayfire.org/arrayfire-rust/arrayfire/struct.Array.html#method.cast) is `cast<T: HasAfEnum>(&self) -> Array`

`Array` type doesn't have type parameters. It is the `cast` method which has one. You need to provide type parameter to the `cast` method using turbofish syntax `::<_>`

`let im2 = im.cast::<u8>();`

Comment: Thanks a lot! didn't know about the turbofish syntax.